# ERROR: undefined method `closed?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: docker, chef-infra

I have workstation and chef server on different machine and docker running on other machine.When i bootstrap from workstation to run chef-client inside docker container. it give me error as after installing chef client on docker Conatiner.

```
 knife bootstrap 10.88.201.19 -p 49153 -x root -P hyl4fL3X7OaH -r role[role_apache]

10.88.201.19 Starting Chef Client, version 11.18.6
10.88.201.19 Creating a new client identity for e381976281bd using the validator key.
10.88.201.19 [2015-02-21T14:22:21+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
10.88.201.19 Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 1.562238601 seconds
10.88.201.19 [2015-02-21T14:22:21+00:00] ERROR: undefined method `closed?' for nil:NilClass
10.88.201.19 [2015-02-21T14:22:21+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully
```

Comment: I would say there is some resolution problem between chef's node (the container) and the chef server. Can you post full stackrace (`/var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out`), and node's client.rb (`/etc/chef/client.rb`)?

Comment: log_location     STDOUT
chef_server_url  "https://10.88.200.224:443"
validation_client_name "chef-validator"

Comment: what do you mean by resolution problem..??

Comment: Your chef server and the nodes has to be able to resolve themselves using their fqdns.

Comment: For this what should i do ??

Comment: HI Javier..I got the solution...When i remove the proxy from client.rb and run it using chef-client ,then it run fine.....but when i do bootstrap from workstation then it always create client.rb in node machine and the problem is ,it also copy the proxy in client.rb because of that it is falling while doing bootstrapping..So what i can do so that it donot attach proxy while generating client.rb in node machine

Comment: II'm missing something? Where is the proxy? In chef server ip?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71409/discussion-between-javier-cortejoso-and-gaurav).